# Python - Name parsing for email checking

Tags: python, string, parsing, combinations

I'm trying to build a script that create different variations of a person's name to test its email. Basically, what I want the script to do is:

- If I input "John Smith" I need to get in return a list containing `[john, johnsmith, john.smith, john_smith, smith, jsmith, j.smith, smithj, smith.j, j_smith, smith_j,smithjohn, smith.john, smith_john, etc]`
- If I input "John May Smith" I need to get in return a list containing `[john, johnmay, johnsmith, john.may, john.smith, john_may, john_smith, jmay, jsmith, j.may, j.smith, j_may, j_smith, johnmaysmith, john.may.smith, john_may_smith, jms, johnms, john.m.s, john_m_s, jmsmith, j.m.smith, j_m_smith, j.m.s, j_m_s, jmays, j.may.s, j_may_s, etc]`. Technically, it would be three lists with name parts: `[j, john][m, may][s, smith]` that would mix in different orders and the parts could be separated or not by "." or "_".
- John Smith and John May Smith are only examples, I should be able to enter any name, decompose it and mix its parts, initials and separators ('.' and '_').

To decompose a name I'm using the following:

```
import nameparser 
name="John May Smith"
name=nameparser.HumanName(name)

parts=[]
for i in name:
    j=[i[0],i]
    parts.append(j)
```

This way `parts` gets like this:

```
[['j', 'john'], ['m', 'may'], ['s', 'smith']]
```

Note that the list in this case has three sublists, however it could have been 2, 4, 5 or 6.

I created another list called separators:

```
separators=['.','_']
```

My question is:
What is the best way to mix those lists to create a list of possible email local-parts* as described in the example above? I've been burning my brain to find a way to do it for a few days but haven't been able to.

*Local-part is what comes before the @ (in jmaysmith@apple.com, the local part would be "jmaysmith").

Comment: Why do you get values such as `smithj`, `smith_j`, and `smith.j`, but not `smithjohn`, `smith_john`, and `smith.john`?  Is this intentional?  If so, I think the rules of how the parts can be combined need to be defined better.

Comment: Thanks @huck_cussler. This cases you've mentioned should be considered too! I've edited and added it.

Comment: Obligatory reminder of your imminent failure http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Perhaps using `itertools.product` might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following code should do what you want

```py
from nameparser import HumanName
from itertools  import product, chain, combinations

def name_combinations(name):
    name=HumanName(name)

    parts=[]
    ret=[]
    for i in name:
        j=[i[0].lower(),i.lower()]
        ret.append(i.lower())
        parts.append(j)

    separators=['','.','_']
    for r in range(2,len(parts)+1):
        for c in combinations(parts,r):
            ret = chain(ret,map(lambda l: l[0].join(l[1:]),product(separators,*c)))
    return ret

print(list(name_combinations(name)))
```

In your examples I have not seen `jms`, `j.s` or `js` in your examples. If that is intentional feel free to clarify what should be excluded.

For reference: The output is

```py
>>> print(list(name_combinations("John Smith")))
['john', 'smith', 'js', 'jsmith', 'johns', 'johnsmith', 'j.s', 'j.smith', 'john.s', 'john.smith', 'j_s', 'j_smith', 'john_s', 'john_smith']
>>> print(list(name_combinations("John May Smith")))
['john', 'may', 'smith', 'jm', 'jmay', 'johnm', 'johnmay', 'j.m', 'j.may', 'john.m', 'john.may', 'j_m', 'j_may', 'john_m', 'john_may', 'js', 'jsmith', 'johns', 'johnsmith', 'j.s', 'j.smith', 'john.s', 'john.smith', 'j_s', 'j_smith', 'john_s', 'john_smith', 'ms', 'msmith', 'mays', 'maysmith', 'm.s', 'm.smith', 'may.s', 'may.smith', 'm_s', 'm_smith', 'may_s', 'may_smith', 'jms', 'jmsmith', 'jmays', 'jmaysmith', 'johnms', 'johnmsmith', 'johnmays', 'johnmaysmith', 'j.m.s', 'j.m.smith', 'j.may.s', 'j.may.smith', 'john.m.s', 'john.m.smith', 'john.may.s', 'john.may.smith', 'j_m_s', 'j_m_smith', 'j_may_s', 'j_may_smith', 'john_m_s', 'john_m_smith', 'john_may_s', 'john_may_smith']
```